# permutation with two sets in itertools using python

Tags: python, linux

I having trouble in rewriting length python code in much more pythonic way.
Here is what I have tried, it also contains an example how I want my final code to look like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import itertools
import os

freq = [2400000,2000000,1600000,1200000,800000]

freq_set = [
        [ i for i in itertools.combinations(freq,1)],
        [ i for i in itertools.combinations(freq,2)],
        [ i for i in itertools.combinations(freq,3)],
        [ i for i in itertools.combinations(freq,4)]
        ]

cores = [[0,4],[1,5],[2,6],[3,7]]

sets = [[0,4],[0,4,1,5],[0,4,1,5,2,6],[0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7]]

# 5 10 10 5 ; 1 3 5 7
for freq_set_val in range(0, len(freq_set)):
        if freq_set_val == 0:
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][0] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][0] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][0] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][1] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                print "do something"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][1] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][0] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][1] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][1] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                print "do something"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][2] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][0] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][2] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][1] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                print "do something"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][3] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][0] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][3] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][1] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                print "do something"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][4] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][0] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][4] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][1] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                print "do something"
        if freq_set_val == 1:
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][0] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][0] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][0] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][1] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][1] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][2] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][1] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][3] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                print "do something"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][1] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][0] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][1] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][1] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][2] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][2] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][2] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][3] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                print "do something"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][2] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][0] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][2] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][1] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][3] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][2] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][3] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][3] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                print "do something"

                print "so onn"
        if freq_set_val == 2:

                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][0] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][0] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][0] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][1] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][1] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][2] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][1] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][3] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][2] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][4] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                change = "echo "+ freq_set[freq_set_val][2] +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ sets[freq_set_val][5] + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                print "do something"
```

Essentially I want to keep flipping a set of cores with a particular frequency level.
so after every `change` statement. I would write `os.system(change)`

Could you please help me out here? 
I also tried implementing the same using shell. but the problem would be not having the `itertools` package.
Please feel free to change the `title of question` I did not know how to phrase it.

This is how it looks now. A prettier version is always better :) but i did not know how to enhance it

```
for freq_set_val in range(0, len(freq_set)):
        if freq_set_val == 0:
                for freq in range(0, len(freq_set[freq_set_val])):
                        for val in range(0, len(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq])):
                                change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][val]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][0]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                                change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][val]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][1]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                                print "do something"
        if freq_set_val == 1:
                for freq in range(0, len(freq_set[freq_set_val])):
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][0]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][0]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][0]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][1]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][1]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][2]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][1]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][3]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        print "do something"

        if freq_set_val == 2:
                for freq in range(0, len(freq_set[freq_set_val])):
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][0]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][0]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][0]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][1]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][1]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][2]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][1]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][3]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][2]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][4]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][2]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][5]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        print "do something"

        if freq_set_val == 3:
                for freq in range(0, len(freq_set[freq_set_val])):
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][0]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][0]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][0]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][1]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][1]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][2]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][1]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][3]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][2]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][4]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][2]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][5]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][3]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][6]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][3]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][7]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
                        print "do something"
```

Comment: So basically this code does what you want, you just want it to be more prettier and less repetitive?

Comment: Yes, and I will append what I came up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def change_freq(freq_set, freq_set_val, freq, i1, i2):
    change = "echo "+ str(freq_set[freq_set_val][freq][i1]) +"> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu"+ str(sets[freq_set_val][i2]) + "/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
    # os.system(change)

for freq_set_val in range(0, len(freq_set)):
    for freq in range(0, len(freq_set[freq_set_val])):       
        for i in range(0, (freq_set_val+1)*2): 
            change_freq(freq_set, freq_set_val, freq, i/2, i)

        if freq_set_val == 0:
            print "dosomething"
        if freq_set_val == 1:
            print "dosomething"
        if freq_set_val == 2:
            print "dosomething"
        if freq_set_val == 3:
            print "dosomething"
```

Comment: Something very similar. but it looks like we are missing a loop.
`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`
I will look into that. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I lost you at `enumerate(range(0, len(...)))`. What the hell are you doing there?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think there's a Pythonic way to do this. Once you go deep enough into this kind of combinatorial mayhem you can't hope for something that's intrinsically readable. However, this can still be made fairly compact. Creating the most appropriate abstraction would depend on precisely how you intend to generalize the pattern, and may require a firm understanding of the underlying mathematics. (This makes me think of tensor products, but my undergraduate physics education is slowly but surely fading from my cognitive grasp...) I couldn't tell from your examples exactly where you want each sequence to end or if you really intended to use every combination you generated at the top, but a couple of functions like this could be a starting point for generating the patterns of integers you need (Python 2.7):

```
def repeating_range(start, stop, repeat):
   return reduce(add,itertools.izip(*itertools.tee(xrange(start,stop),repeat)))

def collated_repeating_range(grouping, stop, repeat):
   return reduce(add,reduce(add,itertools.izip((repeating_range(start, start+grouping, repeat)
                                             for start in xrange(stop)))))

for freq_set_val in range(0, len(freq_set)):
   offset = freq_set_val+1
   for pair in itools.izip(collated_repeating_range(offset,5,2), itools.cycle(xrange(offset*2))):
      print pair
```

Comment: `reduce(add,x)` is better spelt either `sum(x)` or `itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)`